# Search a range using values from an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm trying to write a small macro to search a range of values (provided by an array full of user input) and, for the most part, return their current row. This range is a printable toolsheet of which I only need to print pages that I make changes too, therefore I am attempting to simplify my job by inputting the tools that have been updated, and having the macro tell me what pages to print.

I tried to make that as understandable as possibly, but let me know if clarification is needed.

The problem arises when I try to search the sheet using 'Application.WorksheetFunction'

```
Sub FunWithArrays()

Dim ToolNumber()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

ReDim ToolNumber(1)

    Do

        ToolNumber(i) = InputBox("Please type the name of the tool with proper capitalization.", "Tool Number")
        ReDim Preserve ToolNumber(UBound(ToolNumber) + 1)
        i = i + 1

    Loop Until ToolNumber(i - 1) = "Done"

    MsgBox "Thank you for inputting the tool numbers.", vbOKOnly, "Input Complete"

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ToolNoRow As Range
    Dim PageNo As Double

    For j = 1 To (i - 2)

        ToolNoRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Range("A:A").Text.Find(what:=ToolNumber(j), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        PageNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((ToolNoRow / 1), 0)

        MsgBox "Please print page " & PageNo

    Next

End Sub
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I fully understand how you macro works, since it looks like you want to return row numbers but you talk about returning page numbers.

However, if you want to return the range of a cell in which a given input is found (since you have declared `ToolNoRow As Range`) you would do this by:

```
Set ToolNoRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Text.Find(what:=ToolNumber(j), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Note that you would have to state in what sheet you want to perform the search.

If you instead want to return the row in which this input is found, you could declare `ToolNoRow as Long` and then use:

```
ToolNoRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Text.Find(what:=ToolNumber(j), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
```

You should probably include some error handling in your code, because Excel would return an error message whenever a search item is not found.

Comment: Okay, so I set 'ToolNoRow' to long and added the .Row after that line, and that worked. Now how do I round a value up in VBA?

What I am trying to do is:

> I figured each printed page has 46 rows of the worksheet on it
> Rounding (RowNo/Rows per page) up should return the page number to print
> Have these page numbers displayed to the user, or at least in some usable form

Comment: In that case your own solution with using the `RoundUp` function should work reasonably well. Just divide by 46 instead of 1. That is, change the line to: `PageNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((ToolNoRow / 46), 0)`

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be running smooth. Now on to add more functionality!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You may need to mod the logic after you get the cell address

```
Dim ToolNumber()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

ReDim ToolNumber(1)

    Do

        ToolNumber(i) = InputBox("Please type the name of the tool with proper capitalization.", "Tool Number")
        ReDim Preserve ToolNumber(UBound(ToolNumber) + 1)
        i = i + 1

    Loop Until ToolNumber(i - 1) = "Done"

    MsgBox "Thank you for inputting the tool numbers.", vbOKOnly, "Input Complete"

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ToolNoRow As Range
    Dim PageNo As Double

    For j = 1 To (i - 2)

        With Range("A:A")
            Set ToolNoCell = Find(what:=ToolNumber(j), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    c.Value = 5
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With
        'Do whatever Here
        PageNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((ToolNoRow / 1), 0)

        MsgBox "Please print page " & PageNo

    Next
```